# Kubernetes REST API - how to get pod logs when more than one container is running?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

Forgive me for asking a stupid question but I can't seem to find anywhere in the Kubernetes API reference how to query logs via the REST API if there's more than one container running inside the pod?

`cURL -k -H Authorization: Bearer my-super-secret-token https://kubernetes/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/my-app-1/log`

Returns:

> {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"a
> container name must be specified for pod my-app-1,
> choose one of: [nginx php-fpm]","reason":"BadRequest","code":400}

I tried:

`cURL -k -H Authorization: Bearer my-super-secret-token https://kubernetes/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/my-app-1/nginx/log`

and it results in an error that the resource can't be found.

How do I specify the container name when making an HTTP request to the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - I needed to add **container** using a query parameter:

*?container=nginx*

**Working Example:**

`cURL -k -H Authorization: Bearer my-super-secret-token https://kubernetes/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/my-app-1/log?container=nginx`

Comment: Also see the [`get` read log of the specified Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#get-read-log-of-the-specified-pod) API documentation, which notes "container (in query)" for this option.